# Should there be a correlation between an f1 score and the confusion matrix results in a gradient-boosted decision tree model (XGBoost)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, confusion-matrix

I'm building a decision tree model based on data from the "Give me some credit" Kaggle competition (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/GiveMeSomeCredit/overview). I'm trying to train this model on the training dataset from the competition and then apply to it to my own dataset for research.

The problem I'm facing is that it looks like the f1 score my model gets and the results presented by the confusion matrix do not correlate, and the higher the f1 score is, the worse label prediction becomes. Currently my best parameters for maximizing f1 are the following (the way I measure the score is included):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import xgboost

classifier=xgboost.XGBClassifier(tree_method='gpu_hist', booster='gbtree', importance_type='gain')

params={
    "colsample_bytree":[0.3], 
    "gamma":[0.3],
    "learning_rate":[0.1], 
    "max_delta_step":[1], 
    "max_depth":[4],
    "min_child_weight":[9],
    "n_estimators":[150], 
    "num_parallel_tree":[1], 
    "random_state":[0],
    "reg_alpha":[0], 
    "reg_lambda":[0], 
    "scale_pos_weight":[4],
    "validate_parameters":[1],
    "n_jobs":[-1],
    "subsample":[1],
    }

clf=RandomizedSearchCV(classifier,param_distributions=params,n_iter=100,scoring='f1',cv=10,verbose=3)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

These parameters give me an f1 score of ≈0.46.
However, when this model is output onto a confusion matrix, the label prediction accuracy for label "1" is only 50% (Picture below).
[image: Confusion Matrix with f1 score≈0.46]

When attempting to tune the parameters in order to achieve better label prediction, I can improve the label prediction accuracy to 97% for both labels, however that decreases the f1 score to about 0.3. Here's the code I use for creating the confusion matrix (parameters included are the ones that have the f1 score of 0.3):

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from numpy import nan
final_model = XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', callbacks=None,
              colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=0.7,
              early_stopping_rounds=None, enable_categorical=False,
              eval_metric=None, gamma=0.2, gpu_id=0, grow_policy='depthwise',
              importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints='',
              learning_rate=1.5, max_bin=256, max_cat_to_onehot=4,
              max_delta_step=0, max_depth=5, max_leaves=0, min_child_weight=9,
              missing=nan, monotone_constraints='()', n_estimators=800,
              n_jobs=-1, num_parallel_tree=1, predictor='auto', random_state=0,
              reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=5)

final_model.fit(X,y)

pred_xgboost = final_model.predict(X)

cm = confusion_matrix(y, pred_xgboost)
cm_norm = cm/cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
plot_confusion_matrix(cm_norm, classes=rf.classes_)
```

And here's the confusion matrix for these parameters:
[image: Confusion matrix with f1 score≈0.3]

I don't understand why there is seemingly no correlation between these two metrics (f1 score and confusion matrix accuracy), perhaps a different scoring system would prove more useful?

Answer (score 1):

Would you kindly show the absolute values?
Technically, `cm_norm = cm/cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]` would represent recall, not the accuracy. You can easily get a matrix with a good recall but poor precision for the positive class (e.g. [[9000, 300], [1, 30]]) - you can check your precision using the same code with `axis=0`. (F1 is the harmonic mean of your positive class recall and precision.)

If you wish to optimize for F1, you should also look for an optimal classification threshold on the `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relationship, although not so obvious.  It would help to understand it better if you generate a classification report.

Also, a higher max_rate can change the value of Recall Specificity, which affects one of the class's f1_score in the classification report, but not the f1-score derived from f1_score(y_valid, predictions).  Oversampling can also affect the Recall.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
ClassificationReport = classification_report(y_valid,predictions.round(),output_dict=True)
```

f1_score is the balance between precision and recall.  The confusion matrix shows the precision values of both classes.  With the classification report, I can see the relationship, like in the example below.

```
Classification Report
    precision   recall      f1-score    support
0   0.722292    0.922951    0.810385    23167.0
1   0.982273    0.923263    0.951854    107132.0


Confusion Matrix using Validation Data (y_valid)

True Negative  : CHGOFF (0) was predicted 21382 times correctly (72.23 %)
False Negative : CHGOFF (0) was predicted 8221 times incorrectly (27.77 %)
True Positive  : P I F (1) was predicted 98911 times correctly (98.23 %)
False Positive : P I F (1) was predicted 1785 times incorrectly (1.77 %)
```

[image: Confusion Matrix]